# Accidentally deleted /etc/ - what can I do?

Tags: data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted `/etc/` folder.

Apart from being completely stuffed, what options do I have?

Comment: You mean options other than a reinstall?

Comment: yes..... but I have a feeling there is no other but to rebuild.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to rebuild `/etc/` if you don't have `/etc/` for `sudo` access and stuff.  The simplest solution here might be to backup your home directory or any data you still want, and then reinstall and restore your data later.

Comment: yep. rebuild seems like a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you did a custom install with /home and / on different mount points. You will have to start from scratch or start a live cd and run a hard drive recovery program to recover the /etc folder.

Comment: Not everyone does the first part, versi.  A default install without customized partitioning tends to install everything on one partition and not split the home directory out.

Comment: You sure? If I'm not mistaken I recall Ubuntu defaulting to mount /home, /swap and / on different mount points.

Comment: versi, i have confirmed with both testing of the images myself (launching VMs and installing using defaults, and many installations to hard disks myself) that a default installation creates a `/swap` partition and puts the rest on another partition (for `/`).  There is no third `/home` partition in a default installation (where you do not customize the partitioning any)

Comment: Alright, guess I'm too used to doing custom everything. :/ edited my answer to account for your testing.

Comment: versi, i do agree that would be awesome in a default installation, however with Windows dualboots making three partitions might overtax the MSDOS partition table format.  Which is why I can understand the `/` and `/swap` defaults.  (I custom partition like you said, though, for my systems. ;) )